# Calculating Memory Footprint of GlobalKTables

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I have a Kafka Streams application with GlobalKTables. I would like to compute the memory footprint of the same.

The data in the underlying Kafka topics are compressed using SNAPPY. I couldn't find information about data stored on Ktables. Are records uncompressed once loaded to KTables or are they uncompressed on demand?

Would be very helpful to understand the best way to compute memory footprint of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data would not be compressed.

GlobalKTables (and KTables) use RocksDB to actually hold the data. I guess RocksDB support some compression thought that you could enable.